# Adding ',' operator to the end of each rows in case if it's not present in the file using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a file that consists of '37' columns the structure of the file is separated by ',' in some cases at the end of each row there's no ',' presented so i need to handle that while doing `Bulk insert command` that if no ',' presented at the end of each row then add it automatically and perform the insert.

sample of one row "by default we should have 36 ',' in each row':

```
test,00009,1,2,999,CANCELLED ,1,20,22700,,,,0,,,,,,20140811204912,,,,,,00500016,16,123454009,,,,,,,,0,0.00,0

in some case the file doesn't have same no. of comma or columns:

test,00009,1,2,999,CANCELLED ,1,20,22700,,,,0,,,,,,20140811204912,,,,,,00500016,16,123454009,,,,,,,,0,0.00
```

How to cater this? what will be the syntax in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose Your row is terminated by next line /n in CSV format. So when you run the below command, the data will be fitted in to the columns as per sequence.

When there is no data between two commas null will be inserted and when it finds next row then the data gets updated in to next row of database table.

```
BULK
INSERT CSVTest
FROM 'c:\csvtest.txt'
WITH
( 
 FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  
 ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
 )
GO
```

You data format

```
test1,00009,1,2,999,CANCELLED ,1,20,22700,,,,0,,,,,,20140811204912,,,,,,00500016,16,123454009,,,,,,,,0,0.00,0
test2,00009,1,2,999,CANCELLED ,1,20,22700,,,,0,,,,,,20140811204912,,,,,,00500016,16,123454009,,,,,,,,0,0.00,0
```

Here "test1" row gets in to first row of table and "test2" gets in to second row of table.

Reply to your commment below:

Consider a 5 column table that is comma seperated and terminated by new line.

```
4,1,,3,4
1,,,,,
1,1,
1
6,,,6,
1,1,1
```

and your table structure is like :

```
   col1 :varchar
   col2:varchar
   col3:varchar
   col4:varchar
   col5:varchar
```

When use the above command this is how your table is going to be populated

```
col1    col2    col3   col4   col5
 4       1      null     3      4
 1      null    null     null   null
 1      null      1      null   null
 1      null    null     null   null
 6      null    null     6      null
 1      null    null     null   null
```

It does not matter how many commas are there, if the line terminates with a new line, it will insert it correctly.

As soon as SQL finds a new line, it will skip all the rest of the fields and assign null value to them and start inserting in to new row.

May be new line is not a terminator for new know, so what ever the terminator is, use than in the input command. But since  you have a csv file , you need to worry, new line will be the seperator and the above command will work.

So be it 5 columns as above or be it 37 columns, as in your case - even if there is one value and no comma - when SQL finds a new line, it will start with a new row.

Hope that Helps!

Comment: but in case if the row is missing the last ',' at the end for example in this case: test1,00009,1,2,999,CANCELLED ,1,20,22700,,,,0,,,,,,20140811204912,,,,,,00500016,16,123454009,,,,,,,,0,0.00 will the above code will work?

Comment: the above code works as long as the row is terminated by a new line character. you must have different terminators for columns and for row.

Example 
x,y,z?
So here the column terminator is , and row terminator is ? 

if your code does not have a comma at last, this code will assume it to 
a) a new row if next line character is there
b) add data in same row if no new line symbol is there

Comment: I have edited the above question for better explanation, Can you tell me if the above code will work as well

Comment: But in some cases my source file is missing one attribute & because of that it's showing me an error and it's not getting inserted???                              Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 36

Comment: Then you get your source file correct. At least give it a try.

Comment: I tried that, but there's no other way to get it done through SQL Query?? like for the mismatched column get the value inserted as null or add a separator ',' in between to ensure then number of separator are always the same. because by default no. of separator is '36' if it's less than that it will show error.

Comment: Look I already told you the values will be assigned to columns in sequence. It will give u error if u r trying to add a string value to int. If u have less seperators value will be assigned in sequence and the rest columns will amount to null. It is not possible to assign which value you assign to which column by bulk insert. You will have to edit your file manually